# Want to install linux on a Macbook with a broken CD drive

Tags: linux, mac

I spent the past few hours getting the Debian installer to finally boot from a USB drive. I had to install rEFIt to get that working. So I installed debian, deleted the Mac OS X installation in the process, and now I can't boot into Debian because rEFIt is no longer on the drive since it got erased with Mac OS X it seems. So now I have a Macbook with no CD drive, and no bootable operating system.

I've got a USB flash drive, a windows PC, and a linux PC at my disposal. How the heck can I fix this?

I want the final product to be a Macbook with Debian on it, and nothing else.

Comment: Exactly which MacBook?

Comment: And do you have a Mac OS X install DVD anywhere? One that's valid for that revision of MacBook?

Comment: Spiff: The first Intel Macbook, iirc. Also, I don't have the original disc, but I could burn one.

Comment: Also, is there anyway to make a bootable USB drive of mac os x from windows or linux? I could use that to get mac os x working again on the laptop, then retry linux.

Comment: Does either your Windows or Linux PC have FireWire (a.k.a. IEEE 1394 Serial Bus, i.LINK, sometimes even labeled "DV bus")?

Comment: Okay, never mind. I was beginning to think FireWire Target Disk Mode could have been the solution to your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any direct experience with EFI Macs, but this should work:

1. Install rEFIt to the USB drive (you might need to format to HFS+ first).
2. Use the USB drive to boot Debian.
3. Once you're in Debian, install rEFIt and GRUB 2 to the internal drive (according to [this](http://wiki.debian.org/IntelMac/BootLoader) page).

Comment: How can I format the drive with HFS+ or install rEFIt without access to a Mac?

Comment: Heh. Good question. I guess you could use another Linux box if you have one (or a live CD). There's a commercial program for Windows called "MacDrive" that claims to be able to create HFS+ volumes, but I've never used it.

Comment: Even if I get it formatted, I don't think rEFIt installer will run on anything but OS X :s

Comment: It looks like the 'installer' is just `sudo bless --folder "$DIR" --file "$DIR/$LOADERNAME" --labelfile "$DIR/refit.vollabel` where $DIR is `.` and $LOADERNAME is refit.efi, so you could probably do the same thing with hfsutils on Linux and have it work (I have done this on a PowerPC Mac and it worked fine (with yaboot, not rEFIt), so it might work for the x86 Mac too.)

Comment: I don't think so, "bless" is a Mac OS X command that sets boot options. Although I do have a bit of an idea. I'm going to try running Mac OS X in virtualbox on my PC to install rEFIt on the flash drive. It may just work...

Comment: `bless` is an OSX command, but hfsutils contains a command that does the same thing. If you can get OS X running in VirtualBox that would probably work too, but when I tried it (a year or two ago) it took forever to get it set up properly (and was never very stable, but good enough for this, I guess).

Comment: Looks like I can't virtualize Mac OS X on my new PC because it has a CPU newer than Mac OS X supoorts... Lovely :) Maybe I'll just buy an external USB CD drive.